# Request Method 'Get' Not Supported exception on Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

Why am I getting exception 'method Get not supported'? I dont write any get method in controller or thymeleaf
Controller is:

```
  @Controller
public class UserController {

    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String showForm(Model model){
        User user=new User();
        model.addAttribute("user",user);
        return "register_form";
    }

}
```

thymeleaf code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Spring Boot Registration Form</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <h1>Spring Boot Registration Form</h1>

    <form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${user}"
 th:method="post">
        <label>Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" th:field="*{name}">
    </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think it might be just `method="post"` (without the th): `<form action="#" th:action="@{/register}" th:object="${user}"
 method="post">`

Comment: I solved by adding new @PostMapping Controller

Comment: What do you mean by `adding new @PostMapping Controller`